# Core Warning: Module 'mongodb' already loaded

Tags: php, mongodb

Our apps are set up with Laravel and MongoDB, but we're getting a lot of errors relating to `Core Warning: Module 'mongodb' already loaded` being logged in `Sentry.io`.

Here are the results from `grep -rnw '/etc/php/' -e 'mongodb.so'`

```
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini:1928:extension=mongodb.so
/etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mongodb.ini:1:extension=mongodb.so
/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini:1928:extension=mongodb.so
/etc/php/7.1/mods-available/mongodb.ini:1:extension=mongodb.so
/etc/php/7.3/mods-available/mongodb.ini:1:extension=mongodb.so
/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mongodb.ini:1:extension=mongodb.so
/etc/php/5.6/mods-available/mongodb.ini:1:extension=mongodb.so
```

And here are the results from a generic `php --ini` (notice the error doesn't appear here.)

```
PHP 7.2.15-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb  8 2019 15:38:01) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.15-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Do I need to remove one of the `ini` files above? If so, which one? I'd previously removed duplicate lines of `extension=mongodb.so` from `cli/php.ini` and from `fpm/php.ini`, but the error continues to show up in our `Sentry.io` event logs.

Comment: Did you also restart the web server after editing php.ini?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca well that was it! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If php is being run as a web server module, you need to restart the web server itself after you modify php.ini. The configuration will not be loaded automatically if you don't do that.